# Jboss image upload and http access to show image

Tags: java, jboss, image-uploading

I am uploading images to jboss server by getting the absolute path using the following code

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

The uploaded image is moved to the absolute path and I can access the image using http://test.com:8080/image.jpg

My problem is the image is being uploaded to the tmp directory of jboss server, so i am losing the uploaded images in the next deployment.
I tried uploading the image to various paths to make it work
\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\deploy
and here \jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\work\jboss.web\localhost as well
But fails, I cannot access the image using http://test.com:8080/image.jpg

Kindly help me out in this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a new context to specify a path to access an external folder.

**Steps for Jboss 4 and older versions:**

1. Open your file `/YOURINSTANCE_JBOSS/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml`.
2. Define a new `Context` in the tag `<Host name=”localhost” ...>`

   Example:

   ```
   <Host name=”localhost” ...>
   <Context path=”/myfolder” docBase=”/home/username/my_images” reloadable=”true”></Context>
   ```

   Where **/myfolder** will be the path that you are going to use to access your files, and **/home/username/my_images** the folder where you are going to upload your pictures.
3. Restart JBoss

Now you will be able to access your files with the next path:

```
http://yourserver:yourport/myfolder/filename
```

**Steps for Jboss 5:**

1. Create a new file named `context.xml` into your `WEB-INF` folder with the next content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context allowLinking="true" cookies="true" crossContext="true" override="true">
       <Resources allowLinking="true" className="YOUR_PACKAGE.MyResources" homeDir="/home/username/my_images" />
   </Context>
   ```

   Where **className** is the java class that will access the resources and **homeDir** your external directory.
2. According to this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/config/resources.h) create a new class to access your resources defined in the file `context.xml`

   Example:

   ```
   public class MyResources extends FileDirContext {

   }
   ```

Now you will be able to access your files with the next function:

```
request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(uri);
```

**Steps for Jboss 5 and older versions:**

1. Create a new file named `context.xml` into your WEB-INF folder with the next content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context allowLinking="true" cookies="true" crossContext="true" override="true">  
       <Resources allowLinking="true" homeDir="/home/username/my_images" />  
   </Context>
   ```

   Where **homeDir** is your external directory.
2. Create a symbolic link: `YourDeployedProject.war/myfolder` linked to `/home/username/my_images`

   Windows:

   ```
   mklink /D C:\YOUR_JBOSS_SERVER\server\default\deploy\YourDeployedProject.war\myfolder C:\users\YOURUSER\my_images
   ```

   Linux:

   ```
   YourDeployedProject.war# ln -s /home/username/my_images myfolder
   ```

Now you will be able to access your files with the next path:

```
http://localhost:8080/DeployedProject/myfolder/filename
```

**Steps for Jboss 7:**

JBoss 7 doesn't allow any of the methods for the previous JBoss versions, so the easiest solution is to implement a Servlet to access your files like in the next [link](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I cant fine jboss-web.deployer folder. I have another in this location jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar is this right?

Comment: Maybe is that one. I've done this configuration in our server JBoss 4.2.2AS (I guess it won't be that different in JBoss 5). Check if the file `server.xml` is in the folder you commented.

Comment: Server is not starting if I add the code in server.xml. there is another file called context.xml. If i added here, none of the application in the server is running.

Comment: @Jeyasithar looking about it in the JBoss forums I found this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6368 It seems that from version 5 it only works if your external folder is in `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy`.

Comment: Nice to hear this. Thanks for your answer. I tried this now. But the server is not starting yet. May be I am using in a wrong way. Can you please edit the answer accordingly, so that I can implement the same. Thanks again.

Comment: AM getting this error Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Context not found as a child of Host

Comment: @Jeyasithar I've eddited my post adding solutions for every JBoss server. I hope this will be usefull. The error your are reporting in the last comment occurs only in JBoss 5, please check the other solutions for this version.

Comment: @Jeyasithar you are very welcome! it took time but you did it ;)

Comment: I am using jboss-6.0.0.Final and please tell me what changes i need to do ? I am stuck please reply me soon !!!