# JBoss Managed Domain "Virtual Directory" or Subcontext

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are migrating a web application from a WebLogic cluster to a JBoss cluster and I'm running into an issue configuring a virtual directory to serve out generated documents.

On WebLogic, we used [virtual directories](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039396) to set up a URL location where users could download PDFs generated by the application. JBoss does not have the concept of virtual directories, but [they do offer workarounds](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebLogic+to+AS+7#HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromWebLogictoAS7-ReplaceWebLogicVirtualDirectories). I've been able to get it to work on a standalone server, but I can't find a way of doing it in a [managed domain](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Operating+modes#Operatingmodes-ManagedDomain) configuration. Specifically, I don't think I can create a symbolic link in the deployment directory, as deployments in a domain cluster [are stored in binary format](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment).

In Tomcat, this can be done by [creating a subcontext](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Subcontext-filter-problem-td2100824.html) (see item #2) in the configuration directory.

Is there a way to get a "virtual directory" or "subcontext" with JBoss configured this way?

Details:

- JBoss version is 6.1 EAP (AS7)
- OS is Linux
- Three servers are used, one domain controller and two "regular" servers
- Servers are configured as a managed domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, it looks like JBoss removed anything like this in AS7. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359038/jboss-image-upload-and-http-access-to-show-image) question for a discussion.

In the end, I ended up implementing a servlet to send out the generated files. [This solution](https://community.jboss.org/thread/169647#639271)  was the one I used, since the directory is configured using a java property, letting me change it as needed.